# NGINX configuration for mTLS on the client side

Tags: nginx, ssl, mtls

When configuring mtls in NGINX, to verify upstream certificate, does upstream's TLS chain have to be stored in a cert which is used in `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` property? or just the Root CA certificate?

The server's TLS chain looks approximately like this:

0 - A cert for a company's domain, issued by Digicert Global CA G2

1 - Digicert Global CA G2, issued by Digicert Global Root G2

Comment: In nginx to verify an http or stream SSL/TLS upstream server that sends its intermediate cert(s) (as it should according to standards), you need `proxy_ssl_verify on` (which is not default) _and_ the root cert (only) in `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificates`; see e.g. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html . This has nothing to do with mtls or client side in any way. Also it is not about programming or development, which is the topic of StackOverflow.

Comment: thank you for you response about the root cert. i'm well aware of the `proxy_ssl_verify` and the nginx documentation for `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` where the description is somewhat vague.  It has everything to do with programming and development, at least in my world :)